# Variable Object Declaration Name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Looking to create a set of objects to the size of an array. In a loop I want to define these objects like such:

```
var playersNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];

for(i=0; i < playersNames.length; i++){
    var player[i] = new player();
    player[i].name = playersNames[i];
}
```

But JavaScript doesn't like the `var player[i]`.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array first, then `push()` to it:

```js
var playersNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
var player = [];
function Player() {
 
}

for(i=0; i < playersNames.length; i++){
   player.push(new Player());
   player[i].name = playersNames[i];
}
            
console.log(player);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-allocate the player array:

```js
var playersNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
var nnames = playersNames.length;

var player = new Array(nnames);

for(i = 0; i < nnames; i++){
    player[i] = new Player();
    player[i].name = playersNames[i];
}
```

Comment: if u like to give any answer, please verify that answer before posting. Otherwise, nobody will be helped from the answer and your answers will be put as an underrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this easily-

```js
var playersNames = [
       "name1",
       "name2",
       "name3"
     ];
var players = [];

for(i=0; i < playersNames.length; i++)
{
 players.push( playersNames[i] );
}

console.log(players);
```

Comment: Updated to `players` from `player`

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
var players = playersNames.map(playerName => {
  var myPlayer = new player();
  myPlayer.name = playerName;
  return myPlayer;
});
```

This avoids having to predeclare your `players` array and laboriously push to it one by one. Essentially, `map` does that work for you.

If you redesign your constructor to take the name as a parameter, it's even more compact:

```
var players = playerNames.map(playerName => new player(playerName));
```